# Why did a new canvas that I created get sized HUGE and un-sizable?

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I created a game in Unity that is coming along fine. My next step is adding ui elements like a score field. So I added a new canvas to my scene, but it came in sized HUGE compared to my whole scene. I can not edit the size of the canvas!

You can see it here in my [upload](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gikbgF01rNM).

How can I make my canvas be about the same size as my game?  I am sure it is super easy issues related to my game configuration being set foolishly!

Comment: why do you need a second canvas? can u use the same canvas u are already using for the other ui elements?

Comment: this is the only canvas I have.  I have no other UI elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the normal size for a canvas that is set to `screen space - overlay`. Change the `render mode` and that should allow you to change the transform values